# VAO related functions throw error in OpenGL 3.2 cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I'm writing a OpenGL 3.2 program in cocoa, using one simple vertex array. I can generate the VAO correctly, but when I try to bind it (using glBindVertexArrayAPPLE), I get an invalid operation error. I've read that it's because I use the *APPLE exposed functions, but there are no functions without the *extension* available.

I've read that I have to include "gl3.h", but I'm including the OpenGL framework through XCode and if I try to include it directly I get an error.

Comment: "there are no functions without the extension available" What do you mean by that?

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe he means the headers only include the glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (with APPLE "extension") function declaration.

Comment: @XaitormanX check this if you are on 10.7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203836/working-with-opengl-via-objective-c-cocoa

Comment: @NicolBolas  yes thats what i meant. I'm out at the moment but I'll check the link as soon as i get home. Thanks